# What's the purpose of lonely code blocks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, you can have lonely code blocks, that is, code blocks without an `if`, `function` or something like that preceding them, placed arbitrarily in the code, like this:

```
var a = 3,
b = 4;
{
  a = 50;
  b = 50;
}
alert(a + b); //alerts 100
```

I know some other languages have this (I think C++ does), and they use it for scope control: variables declared inside the lonely code block cannot be accessed outside of it. But since Javascript has function scope rather than block scope, you have to use a self-executing function `(function(){})()` to acheive the same effect.

Is there a purpose for this construct? Have you ever seen anybody use it? Does the spec mention it? Is this just a side effect of the grammar having some sort of general rule about code blocks?

Comment: Specification: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.1

Comment: I think most times you see this the code was written by somebody who mistakenly thought they were getting block scope. Some people who know that it doesn't give scope control use it anyway because they like the visual grouping, but I find that _harder_ to read since it implies scope and leaves me wondering what the original coder meant.

Comment: @FelixKling like anyone can comprehend **that** ...

Comment: @c69: That was not necessarily my intention. I just wanted to show that it is in the spec (re: *Does the spec mention it?*).

Comment: @FelixKling -- this has been deprecated, or there are plans to deprecate it, not sure.  It doesn't work with `use strict` and it won't work in future ES5 engines.

Comment: @cwolves: Interesting, I didn't know that... I guess that indicates that blocks used like this are useless.

Comment: @FelixKling -- Actually I like them :)  They're just _dangerous_ as most people assume you get some kind of scoping out of it.

Comment: From a brief reading of that part of the spec it SEEMS as though something like "var x = {switch(S) case 0: 5; case 1: 10;}" should work, but it doesn't in my version of firefox. Can't be bothered testing other browsers right now.

Comment: @Jeff - you're confusing a `statement` with an `expression` -- statements don't return anything

Comment: @Jeff You can't use a code block in as an expression like that because the parser will try to interpret it as an object literal.

Comment: Ah I see. I was thinking it might have been intended to be as in Ruby where (If my memory serves me...) you can leave return statements implicit - as in function() {...; return 5;} could be the same as function() {...; 5;} but Javascript isn't like that I guess. edit - Ah yes, of course you're right @Peter

Comment: _you have to use a self-executing function to acheive the same effect._ This **looks false** in e.g. Firefox 80: `const myObj={} ; { let temp1=prompt() ; myObj.response = temp1.toUpperCase() } ; Object.freeze(myObj); console.log(temp1);` correctly doesn't keep temp1 around

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I found out after googling my answer for [How are labels used with statements that are not a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783054/how-are-labels-used-with-statements-that-are-not-a-loop/), the lonely code blocks can be related to labels:

```
myLabel:
{
    for(x in y) {
        break myLabel;
    }
}
```

Will break out not only of the loop, but of the outer code block as well.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it some I'm not sure that this is technically the correct answer. By Labeling the code block, you might not consider it to be strictly lonely: instead of a for or function etc. it's attached to a label.

Comment: I'll accept it anyways. ;) I actually learned something from this answer, when the others basically told me what I already knew.

Comment: Changing that break to continue and it fails to work when it should start executing at the top of the code block. Says undefined label! How's that, it was identified when the only difference was it being a break statement!

Comment: @user3015682: This explains the way `continue label;` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue#Using_continue_with_a_label. This is what you tried: http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/9b1xeqsd/. Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/9b1xeqsd/1/. The difference is that in your case you were not labelling the loop statement.

Answer (score 7):

Update (as this question shows up high on Google for "javascript code block"):

With the introduciton of the `let` keyword in ECMAScript 6, code blocks can also be used to limit scope of variables.

```
{
    let x = 20;
    alert(x) // 20
}
alert(x) // undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Only code readability, nothing more.

They do not even give you the advantage of closures:

```
var c = 'fail';
{
    var c = 123;
}
alert(c); //alerts 123
```

([see it live](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtsWx/1/))

Comment: What do you mean by visibility?

Comment: @PeterOlson: I mean **code readability**. This is useful only when reading the code, I know no other reason to do that.

Comment: There are probably some cases where it could be argued that it's more readable. Personally I would never use this syntax for JavaScript.

Comment: @sissonb: I also never use it - I try to write as readable code as possible, without using unnecessary "_constructs_". But the question was about the purpose of such blocks and in fact the only purpose can be (arguable) improvement of code readability. (Unless someone has made a mistake and assumed it will work as `(function(){/* ... */})()`). So, basically, there are two possible reasons: 1) readability, 2) mistake ;)

Answer (score -1):

Only readability.  Other than that, nothing.  Do ***not*** do this as it's not future-proof.  The following will happily break:

```
"use strict";

var a = 3,
b = 4;
{
  a = 50;
  b = 50;
}
alert(a + b); //alerts 100
```

I used to use it myself as it allowed logical separation of functionality, but no longer do due to the above.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and more maintainable to use code paragraphing to denote logical separation?

Comment: @PeterOlson -- I've used this mostly for larger scripts.  Things like `Program Config`, `Handle Command-Line Options`, `Error Handling`, etc are all broken into their own sections and then wrapped with anonymous blocks.  It "enforced" the idea that all code here belongs to a certain group of functionality.  It looks ___very___ clean and clear when done properly