# When creating an javascript object in Chrome Console why does it display the properties that are in quotes

Tags: javascript, object

I have created an object called bicycle:

```
var bicycle = new Object();
{
bicycle.speed  = 0,
bicycle.gear = 1,
bicycle.frame_material = "carbon fiber"
}
```

when I input this into the chrome console it displays the last property. Shouldn't it just create this object and not return anything.

Comment: Weird use of a block statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var bicycle = {
    speed  : 0,
    gear : 1,
    frame_material : "carbon fiber"
};
```

There was no reason to have a separate block that assigns the properties of bicycle. The ["lonely code block"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735841/whats-the-purpose-of-lonely-code-blocks-in-javascript) assigns the properties, but the value of the code block is the value of the last statement in the block (if any). The Chrome console duly prints the value of the last assignment, which is `"carbon fiber"`.

Edit: The rules for how a code block is evaluated can be found in [Sec. 12.1 of the ECMAScript Language Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1).

Comment: First it does not answer the OPs actual question. Second, the code does the same exact thing as OPs. Yes the block statement is weird, but it is not wrong.

Comment: @epascarello - I added an explanation of the output OP was seeing.

Comment: @epascarello No, it's not the same: any assignation returns the assigned value except if it's part of a declaration: `var a=1;` does not return enything, but then `a=2` returns 2.

Comment: @PabloLozano This answer originally was just saying the OP was defining the object... Comment is out of context from what you see now.